# disable browser cache for a specific list of domain names

Tags: php, apache, caching

I am a web developer and I often feel need to disable browser cache for certain domain names   which I am currently developing on as I don't want javascript to cache. Is there a web browser plugin which I can make use of or It is as trivial as changing certain HTTP headers in apache/php configuration.

I work on LAMP stack.

Comment: Which web browser are you using? Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: You could set up your development web server to disable all caching, so you can test while you develop. If a file gets pushed to production, you can change the reference to that file using a [`<filename>?<timestamp/hash/version>` notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206224/better-way-to-prevent-browser-caching-of-javascript-files).

Comment: @MartinRothenberger I switch between Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could serve the javascript files trough a PHP script like: `src="get_script.php?name=jquery.js"` and send the proper headers in `get_script.php`.

Or you could disable the cache on your browser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Or set the headers in your apache:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html