# PHP file_get_contenst on a file.json return cache

Tags: php, json, caching

Im having this problem guys.
In one part of my code I delete an element of the json file

```
[
    {somedata},
    {somedata},
    {somedata} // deleted
]
```

after deleted and fwrite or file_put_contents I redirect to another script
In that script I get the file.json data, but it is like returning the file data cached with that element not deleted yet. only when I press f5 it returns the new data.json file with that item delete.

Anyone knows how can I fix this issue. Ideas.

regards.

Comment: Isn't that what caching is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding no-cache headers to the second script:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

See [How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site) for more info

Comment: I will try that tomorrow at work. thank you. I will let you know.