# Internet Explorer Cache Overriding Output

Tags: javascript, php, forms, internet-explorer

I've got an online tool that has multiple equations that produce results based on other changeable variables. I have a field that adjusts based on what product I have and the number of the products being used. However, when I change the product, the field will still output as if the old variables were in use. To see the output with the new product I have to do a Hard Refresh (ctrl + F5). I have to do this for EACH output that IE had previously seen. So if I previously had Product A and looked at the output for the numbers of 1, 2, and 3 products, then switched to Product B, the output for 1, 2, and 3 products will remain the same. And each one will require a hard refresh before it shows the correct output (note:4,5,6,etc will all show correctly since IE never saw them). I have no idea how to get around this.

IE completely ignores the current equation in favor of whatever it has previously recorded. I have no idea how to get around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting proper no [cache headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)?

Comment: I had set them in manually in the html, but I followed your link and implemented the JS and PHP versions and that seems to have solved it. Thanks!