# chrome back button click refresh the site

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i creating a site online university course registration form but.
i want, when someone use my site if he can click back button or next button in chrome or any browser then site take auto refresh .
Please tell me how that possible.

Comment: Use Cache Control headers.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/681072/299159 ?

Comment: please give some code that can help me...

Comment: Are you using any framework or core php?? Try This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site

Comment: yes it work  thanks for your help. but a tiny problem i use check box but when some one add some check box and then he back it my page is now refresh with your code but check box tick is seen ... how i solve this problem??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure the response contents aren't cached, you should add a `Cache-Control: max-age=0` header to the response, which marks it as uncachable. There are some caveats in that area, but googling on "no cache headers" will make that clear for you.

To make sure the browser doesn't cache the form values (whether or not the response was cached), you should disable autocomplete on the form:

```
 <form ... autocomplete="off">
      ...
 </form>
```

One step further is to investigate the browser's "history API", which you can hook into using libraries such as [Backbone.History](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Comment: wow thanks now my problem is solve <form ... autocomplete="off">
      ...
 </form> 
in it check box tick is not seen so its help ful
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
it can clear my cache 

 and 
thanks Indrasinh Bihola and Gerard van Helden

Answer (score 2):

add this in font page it can refresh page

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

if you use check box then you need to add

```
    <form ... autocomplete="off">
      ...
 </form>
```

this can clear your check box tick.
so if you click back button in mojila or chrome your page will be auto refresh.