# HTML Allow Same File Name Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have a simple HTML file upload input:

```
<input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg" />
```

I want to allow the same file name to be uploaded in a row. For example,

First I upload an image, and then I see it displayed and decide it's not how I like it so I open it up in photoshop (or another photo editor) and I make some changes. Now I want to re-upload it.

With this current input field I can not do that. I must either:

a.) change the name

or

b.) have a way to clear the input field before reuploading

What I want to happen is to have the upload field clear the existing file thus allowing the same file to be uploaded without conflict. Or if HTML has an attribute that allows the same file to be uploaded again (and have the updated changes that were made in photoshop).

I do not want my users to manually clear the input by pressing an x button for several reasons.

**Note:** I can not clear the file input on pop up of the select box because if they press cancel it will still remove the image. I know I can avoid this by saving the image before removing it but this seems like a very ugly hack.

Can anybody help me out with this? Is there a simple hack/work-around or is this not possible?

Comment: What are you using to retrieve the file from the backend; move_uploaded_file() ?  if so, you need to unlink() the filename before adding it again.

Comment: I guess I'm just speaking from recent trouble doing this in PHP

Comment: I use the copy function.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used a file upload field, I was able to just hit F5, re-submit the form when prompted by the browser, and it would upload the file with changes applied.

So it sounds like you're doing something more than just a "simple" file upload. If you're listening for `onchange`, consider calling `.reset()` on it after successful upload to clear it out.

Comment: This is a fine way for me or somebody who understands that as an option. But for my users I cannot assume they know this.

Comment: Also, I can not clear it after an upload because I use it in PHP to get the location.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the image would just be cached in your browser.  Check out this post for preventing caching [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

from the link above:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```