# Session Expires Only in Internet Explorer automatically

Tags: php

Folowing code always redirect me to my page '/index.php?err=2' only in Internet explorer. Chrome, firefox and safari doesnt have this issue so this is clearly issue of session only in IE. I have tried following suggestions given on the web but it doesn't helped me anyhow:

[How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

[How to change the session timeout in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php)

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_useremail'])){
      header('Location: index.php?err=2');
 }else{ 
    #code if session is not expired
}
?>
```

and tried set this as header also.. i thought one of this can be issue.. but IE still throws me out to index.php..Below code is taken from [here](https://genotrance.wordpress.com/2006/11/23/session-cookies-rejected-by-internet-explorer/).

```
<?php header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us some details about your dev environment, like the OS, if you're using Xampp, Wamp or any other and which version of PHP you are running on?

Furthermore, your last link, I read the article and the thing is what you are using, the guy says espicifically that it didn't work at all for him, so, why are you trying it?

Well, maybe you shall check the Final Solution of the article (at the end of it), try it and give us some news :)

Comment: Actually it is on live web application. its on apache server. I use windows 7 as development platform. It didn't work for him i know but with the hope it work for me so i tested it. negatively.

Comment: And i used the suggestion given with "Final Solution of the article ". Still no good news.

Comment: Which version of PHP ?