# PHP: Session works only after refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating the code to add products to a cart using PHP.
The script below works, but the added product can be shown only after refreshing the page.

```
  if ( isset( $_GET[ 'add' ] ) ) {

    $query = query( "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = " . escape_string( $_GET[ 'add' ] ) );
    confirm( $query );

    while ( $row = fetch_array( $query ) ) {
      if ( $row[ 'quantity' ] != $_SESSION[ 'product_' . $_GET[ 'add' ] ] ) {
        $_SESSION[ 'product_' . $_GET[ 'add' ] ] += 1;
        redirect( $url );

      } else {
        $session->message( "We only have " . $row[ 'quantity' ] . " " . $row[ 'title' ] . " available" );
        redirect( $url );
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the **query** function:

```
 function query( $sql ) {
    global $connection;

    return mysqli_query( $connection, $sql );
  }
```

This is the very simple **redirect** function:

```
 function redirect( $location ) {
    return header( 'Location:' . $location );
 }
```

I cannot understand why.

Comment: try this:  redirect($url);exit;

Comment: We can't see what your redirect function does.

Comment: We also don't know what the session variable is,  is Confirm a native function? I havent seen that one before.

It probably doesn't redirect properly, like suggested by the other commenter. It might be because the redirect function is faulty or output has occured before etc.

Comment: We also don't know what your `query` method does. You're also not adding anything in this code - you're only `SELECT`ing. Is this ajax?

Comment: Hi,
I added the missing functions in my post.

Comment: Im assuming this isnt ajax, because why would you redirect from an ajax script.. Which means we need much more info in order to help you out.  What you've shown appears very confused (why redirect inside a while loop on both true/false sides of an if statement?).  We need the HTML to provide context, and some clearer explanation of exactly what you are expecting/seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think session is working but your browser shows a cached page and when you refresh it then it updates the page.

Comment: Hi Shan,
thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: You are welcome. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

Comment: Hi Shan, 
thanks for the link. Unfortunately the problem has not been solved.

Comment: Sorry for that, when response is received does it redirects the page?

Comment: Yes, it redirects the page.

Comment: After redirect you never set session value, then how it can show correct value after refresh?
Instead of redirect, print session value to make sure it is changing or not.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for accepting my answer. Infact it is my 1st answer which is accepted as correct, Thanks again :) I would like suggest you to show solution of your problem if anyone else face this problem could solve it easily.