# Delayed response in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am preparing an university project: online book selling shop environment.
I have a PHP page that updates few values in a table while another PHP page that runs a SELECT query to display the values of table. The problem is after the first page updates the value, the second page doesn't display the changes instantly. There is a handful amount delay before the changes take effect in display. What could possibly be the reason? And how could the same be solved?

P.S. I am using these PHP pages to implement JSON Parsing for my Android Development(using volley)

First one:

```
<?php

include_once("connect_seller.php");
$table= $_GET['pin'];
$orderid= $_GET['oid'];
$sellerid= $_GET['id'];
$orderstatus= $_GET['ostat'];

$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM " . $table . "WHERE order_id='$orderid' AND status=-1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if($res["COUNT(status)"] > 0)
{

    $query = "UPDATE " . $table . "SET order_status='$orderstatus', status='served' , served_by='$sellerid' WHERE order_id='$orderid'";


    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
    {

        echo '{"maal":[{';
        echo '"message":"success"}';
        echo ']}';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '{"maal":[{';
        echo '"message":"error"}';
        echo ']}';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '{"maal":[{';
        echo '"message":"taken"}';
        echo ']}';
}
?>
```

Second one:

```
<?php
include_once("connect_seller.php");

if( isset($_GET['pin'])) {

    $table= $_GET['pin'];

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(status) FROM " . $table . "WHERE status=-1";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($res["COUNT(status)"] > 0)
    {

        $query1 = "SELECT order_id, timestamp, zip, status, order_status FROM  " . $table . "WHERE status=-1";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
        $myArray = array();

        while($row = $result1->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $myArray[] = $row;
        }



        echo '{"maal":';
        echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        echo "}";
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'null';
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: don't see any relation with Android

Comment: Maybe just browser cache. Make sure to set a header from the second page that tells the browser not to cache it.

Comment: Check the database via PHPMyAdmin or whatever tool you have to confirm if the data actually went through immediately after posting it. Get back to me on whatever you find.

Comment: Is it an ajax HTTP request ?

Comment: @GolezTrol how to do that? Please give an example

Comment: @LeyeOdumuyiwa yes, the data gets updated instantly, it's just the php page that takes few minutes to take effect

Comment: @HorsSujet no, it isn't an Ajax http request

Comment: @SaptakDas PHP, Header, Cache. Put in Google.

Comment: SQL injection spotted, + MySQL Syntax error near `"WHERE ` and `"SET` (missing blankspace).

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this " $myArray[] = $row; "

Comment: @LeyeOdumuyiwa it is to encode the result into array which later is is encoded into JSON object. It is done that way to let my android app understand it. My issue is different, it's about delayed response as I've said earlier

Answer (score 0):

Your delayed reponse is maybe your cache which keep the value, try :

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

- [How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

Comment: @SaptakDas Can you copy/paste the header of request and response (of the first and second page) ? Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423061/view-http-headers-in-google-chrome