# How to properly destroy PHP session in my code

Tags: php

I have created 3 files.

The first one is my index.php file where all of my HTML is stored

```
// index.php file
<?php 
session_start();
?>

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

The second one is my login file (part of this) where i create sessions

```
//login.php
$_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
$_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
$_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
$_SESSION['u_log'] = $row['user_login'];
header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
exit();
```

And the last one is for logout where i try to destroy my sessions

```
//logout.php
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: ../login.php?logout");
    exit();
}
```

So the problem is next... as you can see from the code, i check in my index.php file, if section is not set, to redirect users to login.php. After successfully login and logout, i try to visit the home page 'index.php' i expected browser to redirect me to login.php but it didn't happen, i see just white screen without html code when i inspect, there are also none errors in console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: You are probably just violating the “no output before sending headers” rule … by introducing unnecessary extra white space between `?>` and `<?php`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: you say you have no error logs at all? Assuming you've started the session correctly, all you need to do really is to simply clear the session data with `$_SESSION = [];` and [ensure the browser does not cache the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site).

Comment: *"there are also none errors in console"* ... well, no - PHP runs on the server, your JavaScript console knows nothing about it.

Comment: Are you start session on logout.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: i should have one page that include the 3 files, and then put `session_start()` function in it. The Session ID is not the same because `logout.php`, `login.php` don't have `session_start()`

Comment: @MartinM "This one that to copy is totally different, not connected with the set or unset of session" It may well be related. You should share the error you're getting.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php says "Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.". I don't think you should be using this function. You can use `$_SESSION = array();` to explictly reset the session array. session_destroy() doesn't delete them either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are displaying some content **before** changing the header. Then, the header was already sent. and `header(something)` won't work.

```
// index.php file
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!-- there is a space below. -->

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Change your code to

```
// index.php file
<?php 
session_start(); // not closing php tag just below

if (!isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

When you are rendering a page, the server send to the browser a HTTP Message.

(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body))

> The request/response message consists of the following:
>
> - Request line, such as GET /logo.gif HTTP/1.1 or Status line, such as HTTP/1.1 200 OK,
> - Headers
> - An empty line
> - Optional HTTP message body data

If you send some message body data (even a space) before using `header();`, a header will already be send. Doing `header()` after will have no effects, since the HTTP Message is already defined

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That's it, it work right i expect right now!

Comment: Do you understand why?

Comment: I try to search something and to go deep in this solution but i can't find nothing... newbie in php...