# How to force browser to load new WordPress site instead of cached site

Tags: wordpress, caching

I recently uploaded a new WordPress website using Duplicator. The old website was made without a CMS and just HTML and CSS.

Now users users aren't seeing the new website and instead they see the old website.

I know that if they the users clear their cache they will see the new website, but they aren't very tech savvy, so isn't a viable solution.

Is there someway to force users to see the new website and clear their browser cache. I have tried numerous things such as: having the host clear their cache solution, putting text in the .htaccess file that should supposedly make the website not use any form of cache.

I really hope some of you got a solution - it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running a PHP site, follow this: [How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

Otherwise if you are running HTML, go for the following meta-code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I added it with a WP plugin like this: https://prnt.sc/t4hhdr 
Would that be sufficient or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: If the website is build upon PHP it should be enough with the <?PHP ?> part :) Using them both is not really necessary since they apply the same effect. But the important question is, did it work? @langbager

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Do you have any other ideas?