# Image generated by PHP is not updated on some browsers

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP page which displays image chart generated by different PHP file. But the image is not updated on some older browsers (e.g e-reader browser). Any idea how to force refresh/image regeneration?

Thanks
Peter

```
<img src="image.php" alt="Image created by a PHP script">
```

Content of image.php

```
    // Call Polyline Function
$draw->polyline($points);
  
// Create an Imagick Object
$image = new Imagick();
  
// Create new Image
$image->newImage(140, 100, 'white');
  
// Set Image Format
$image->setImageFormat("png");
  
// Draw Image
$image->drawImage($draw);
  
header("Content-Type: image/png");
  
// Display the output image
echo $image->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

Comment: Unfortunately not, added headers from link above, but still the same (updated on Firefox, Chrome, IE but not on old browser in e-reader).


<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>