# How to disable CSS caching in development, working with a PHP back end?

Tags: php, css, browser-cache

I'm working on php/css project through localhost and nearly every time I change css and reload page, css remains unchenged until I delete cookies, cache and other site data (somethimes even then it doesn't work straight away). Css is linked correctly, as well as aeverything else, so this is not a problem with code, but with browser/cache.

My question is- is there a way to resolve this issue other than deleting cookies and cache every time I change something in my css?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache busting via params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692665/cache-busting-via-params)

Comment: just a quick tip: if you reload the page with `ctrl + f5`, the cache is cleared and changes are shown... way faster than any server side settings.

Comment: @AlonEitan I tried it several times, but it doesn't change anything :'(

Comment: @toffler thanks for the tip, I've been using it before and I just switched to ```ctrl+R``` for no reason, but I had no idea that ```ctrl+F5 ``` clears cache. Anyways, it doesn't change anything

Comment: If this doesn't work, you can add a "changing" param to the include of your css in php... something like `".../file.css?v=".time()"`. If it is still not working, it might be not a caching problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Browser cache for php site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site)

Comment: Your browser most likely also have a Developer tools section, which usually contains a setting for disabling client cache. [Here's how you do it in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments and answers were helpful, but none of them solved the problem long term.

After some experimenting, I found an answer: disable saving cookies and cache for given site, in

`chrome settings > advanced > Privacy and security > Sites that can never use cookies`

Answer (score 3):

Please add a query parameter to CSS with dynamic file modified time:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime("style.css");?>" />
```