# PHP Alternate between 2 cookie values

Tags: php, cookies

I have two banners on the same page and I want to display just one at a time, each time I refresh the page it should display the other one.
The containers of the two banners have a specific class called "cta1" and "cta2".
Unfortunately, it does not alternate.
The PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59'));
if(isset($_COOKIE['cta'])){
    if($_COOKIE['cta']=='two') {
        echo '<style>.cta2{display:block !important;}</style>';
        echo '<style>.cta1{display:none !important;}</style>';
        setcookie('cta', 'one', $time+186400, '/');
    }else{  
        echo '<style>.cta1{display:block !important;}</style>'; 
        echo '<style>.cta2{display:none !important;}</style>';
        setcookie('cta', 'two', $time+186400, '/');
    }
}else{
    setcookie('cta', 'two', $time+186400, '/');
    echo '<style>.cta1{display:block !important;}</style>';
    echo '<style>.cta2{display:none !important;}</style>';
}
?>
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="cta1">banner 1</div>
<div class="cta2">banner 2</div>
```

Comment: Make sure the browser isn't caching the page.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works. However, your code is clearly incomplete, the HTML is missing, so I added that myself. Perhaps there's a problem there? Or it could be [the caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site) as Barmar says.

Comment: At this point I'm pulling my hair.
Google Chrome works.
Edge and Firefox not.
I will turn white hair before I get married :)

Comment: Yes, that's the same HTML that I created. Have you tried the answer in the link I gave? It will prevent caching.

Comment: It was the hosting. They are caching everything. I asked them to exclude this cookie from caching. Weirdest thing ever :)